# How to create a generic Jenkins stage, where the agent, and the steps are parameters?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have multiple jenkinsifles, doing basically the same thing:

```
pipeline{
  parameters { ... }
  environment { ... }
  stages {
    stage ('setup') { ... }
    stage ('run') {
      agent { AGENT }
      steps { STEPS }
    }
  }
```

The `STEPS & AGENT` parameters are values I get in the `setup` stage. Is it possible to define somewhere a function that returns a stage?

e.g.

```
def stage_factory(name, agent, steps, post ...){
  return
    stage (name) {
      agent { agnet }
      steps { steps }
      post { post }
    }
}
}
```

which later will be called inside the pipeline, right after the setup stage
?

Answer (score 1):

The following works in scripted pipeline, you need to try the declarative syntax yourself. Note the use of surrounding `{}`

```
def stage_factory(name, agent, steps, post ...){
    return {
        node(agent){
            stage (name) {
                steps()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this approach you need to put the post action in try-catch blocks, but this is the gist of it.

If you change it like so, you can even pass the steps to it as you would expect from a Jenkins stage.

```
def stage_factory(name, agent){
    return { steps ->
        node(agent){
            stage (name) {
                steps()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
def myDtage = stage_factory("foo", "bar")
myStage{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Looks nice. I'll check it out tomorrow. Try catch will have the same effect as post? I mainly need two post scenarios - abortion and failure.

Comment: you'll need to check for the exception type in the catch-block but it should work just fine.